# Как правильно провести исследовательское тестирование?

Tags: jmeter

Всем привет. Поставили задачу узнать максимальную нагрузку которую выдержит система для того чтобы понять нужно ли добавлять мощности или нет(**требований или каких то документов для тестирования нет от слова совсем**). Я нагрузочным тестированием не особо силен и не совсем понимаю что да как.
Описываю ситуацию:
Начал с тестирования апи, выбрал первый ендпоинт который отвечает за поиск контрагентов, апи отправляет запрос через Elasticsearch и возвращает список компаний в формате json соответствующих отправленному запросу. В Jmeter создал 3 Thread Group с параметрами (users - 1000, ramp-up period - 100, loop count - 4) постепенно увеличивая кол-во пользователей, в каждой группе создал http request где в параметрах выставил токен и отправляемое значение по которому будет идти поиск (ТОО, КАЗ, ИП)
**Вопрос первый** - правильно ли я вообще всё делаю?
**Вопрос второй** - на какие данные в Summary Report мне опираться когда я буду составлять отчет о тестировании
**Вопрос третий** - как этот отчет вообще должен выглядеть)
**Вопрос четвертый** до какого момента мне продолжать увеличивать кол-во пользователей? до появления ошибок или опять же на какие данные в отчете мне опираться?
**Вопрос пятый** - почему 1 и тот же ендпоинт выдает разное кол-во запросов в секунду при отправке разных значений(ТОО, ИП, КАЗ и т.д)?
Заранее благодарю за помощь! Я в 99% случаев занимаюсь функциональным тестированием так что прошу строго не судить если вопрос оказался тупым
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. > правильно ли я вообще всё делаю?

   Я бы увеличил количество итераций или вообще поставил `-1`, потому что есть ненулевая вероятность, что первые пользователи 4 раза выполнят запрос и все, а следующие еще даже не начнут. Так что в реальности у вас не 1000 пользователей, а меньше.
2. > на какие данные в Summary Report мне опираться когда я буду составлять отчет о тестировании

   Можете отдать "как есть", там особо нечего анализировать.

   Еще посмотрите на [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html), те же результаты там представлены намного нагляднее.
3. Он должен выглядеть хорошо, так чтобы и менеджеры понимали где и когда оно поломается, где первый [bottleneck](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/bottleneck-testing) и что нужно сделать чтобы сервис выдерживал большую нагрузку и разработчики могли понять где узкое место.
4. В идеале количество транзакций в секунду должно увеличиваться пропорционально нагрузке, но скорее всего в один прекрасный момент оно перестанет увеличиваться и или останется на одном уровне или вообще начнет падать из-за увеличивающегося времени отклика. Это называется [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html), скорее всего - вы его и ищете.
5. Потому что у разных сервисов разное время отклика.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь! А нет ли какого нибудь шаблона отчета о исследовательском тестировании? В интернете не могу найти такие. И получается в отчет мне все 3 кейса заносить? (то есть ендпоинт search со значением ТОО, выдает такие данные, ендпоинт search со значением ИП , такие данные и т.д)